# Toast notification when app in background in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I want to send a toast notification to the action center when my app is in background. So I have set up a Timer, when I start the timer from the app, after 10 sec it produces a toast notification. Now when I try it in the debugger, the toast is produced, even if I press the home button or if I suspend the app using debugger suspend option. But when I deploy the app , it is not producing the toast when I start the timer and  click home button. Can anyone suggest a solution for this..?

Adding the Code

```
    private Timer stateTimer;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(timer_Tick);
        TimeSpan delayTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        TimeSpan intervalTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Timer notification_timer = new Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent,   delayTime, intervalTime);
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object state)
    {
        ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Download has complete"));
        toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Download has complete"));

        IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "{\"type\":\"toast\",\"param1\":\"12345\",\"param2\":\"67890\"}");
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're debugging your app is never suspended until you explicitly choose suspension from the lifecycle events in Visual Studio. So when you press the home button your app actually continues running.

This is not the case when running the app without an attached debugger on an actual device. Once you hit the home button your app gets suspended and won't run until it's resumed.

You would have to use a background task to execute code in background.

Comment: Hi Fred, I used the lifecycle events in Visual Studio to suspend the app. In that case  i am getting the toast notification. But not when it is detached from the debugger.

Comment: Hi Fred, I have updated the code. When I click the button in the app, the Button_Click gets called, where I am registering for a timer callback. (As of my understanding this timer callback will be executed in another thread independent of UI thread)Then I will suspend my app using the visual studio suspend option. Then the toast is created properly. But if I deploy and press home it does not create the toast

Comment: I'd consider this an emulator bug. Fact is: In reality your app WILL get suspended after the home button is pressed and your code WILL NOT be executed. You will have to write a background task for this.

Comment: I am trying with a background task. But what should be the triggering point for the background. If possible can u share me code or link of using background task to send a notification.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to download something: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2229233&seqNum=6

Comment: I have created a background task, which is actually triggered by a time zone change. Can I start the background task automatically from the code which is suspended?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70588/discussion-between-fred-and-jose-john-thottungal).